# OpenBSD core dump and /var size

Tags: partition, openbsd, size, core-dump

I'm trying to figure out my [partitioning](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#Partitioning)
which leads to https://man.openbsd.org/disklabel#AUTOMATIC_DISK_ALLOCATION which says:

```
/var        13% of disk.   80M – 2x size of crash dump
```

But how do I know the size of crash dump?
I can't find it neither in OpenBSD's installation guide,
nor in https://man.openbsd.org/savecore.8
nor in the internet at large.

The only clue I've found is in
http://man.openbsd.org/man8/crash.8

> the system dumps the contents of physical memory onto a mass storage
> peripheral device

"physical memory". So do rules of estimating swap partition size apply here as well?

May I ask for some actual numbers/functions/tables? Perhaps similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/49138) answer on swap size?

I am an ordinary user who is not going to test OpenBSD for crashiness but to just run it the more stable the better but for the possibility of a crash be able to report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also [asked on the mailing list](https://marc.info/?t=163611626700001) and got [the answer from Otto Moerbeek](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=163614131802836):

> a crash dump is roughly the size of your physcial mem. Actually the
> max for /var is 4G *plus* 2x physical mem. So the table in the man
> page is not completely right.

By "the table in the man page" he must have meant the one from which I took the:

```
/var        13% of disk.   80M – 2x size of crash dump
```